# How to set up ajax time out in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-video

Below is the snippet of my code that I am using. Actually video that I am loading is of about 1GB, so incase user has medium internet connection, the ajax times out the request, before the video gets fully loaded.

Hence I want to reset ajax time out period to 1 day, so that it doesn't gets timed out.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    console.log("Downloading video...hellip;Please wait...");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'video/video.m4v', true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      if (this.status == 200) {
        console.log("got it");
        var myBlob = this.response;
        var vid = (window.webkitURL ? webkitURL : URL).createObjectURL(myBlob);
        // myBlob is now the blob that the objec8t URL pointed to.
        var video = document.getElementById("video");
        console.log("Loading video into element");
        video.src = vid;
        // not needed if autoplay is set for the video element
        // video.play()
            //alert(1);
            windowLoad();
            $('body').removeClass('loading');
       }
  }
xhr.send();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set the [XMLHttpRequest.timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout)

```
xhr.timeout = 86400000; // 1 day in milliseconds

xhr.ontimeout = function (e) {
  // XMLHttpRequest timed out. Do something here.
};
```